# Multiple insert statements in MySQL using Trigger with Loop

Tags: mysql, database-design, triggers

I have three tables A, B and C.

A table has columns Aid, Aname

B table has Bid, Aid, Aname, Cid, Cname

C table has Cid,Cname

C table is static table and has 6 records (In future it may increase)

Requirement is when data got inserted to Table A, then B Table should be updated with Aid and all each row of Cids with max+1 of Bid.

For each record insert in A table, There should be 6 records inserted in B table (since there are 6 records in C Table)

Is this possible in MySQL using Trigger?

Comment: Did you actually try anything?

Comment: Yes we got a solution similar to as explained here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible using a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER b_update_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON b
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  ...
END
```

however **you really shouldn't duplicate data**.  You should keep `AName` in `table A` and `CName` in `table C`.

Then you can join them to get the same result:

```
SELECT b.bid, a.aid, a.aname, c.cid, c.cname FROM b
INNER JOIN a
  ON a.aid = b.aid
INNER JOIN c
  ON c.cid = b.cid
```